# Symbols do not display on Mac OS X

Tags: r, macos, utf-8

I am trying to display symbols in a plot. My script works perfectly on Linux Fedora 20, but not on Mac OS X 10.10.

When I use for example:

```
cairo_pdf(file='test.pdf')
pdfFonts("serif")
par(family="serif")
plot(1,1, main=expression(delta))
dev.off()
```

It shows a white square in the .pdf on the Mac OS, while it works on Fedora.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

My `sessionInfo()`:

> ```
> > sessionInfo()
> R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
> Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)
>
> locale:
> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages:
> [1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
> [1] tools_3.2.3
> ```

Comment: It works for me with just the regular `pdf()` device.

Comment: Works fine for me on 10.11. What does `pdfFonts()$serif` tell you? Do you have the Times font on your system?

Comment: > pdfFonts()$serif
$family
[1] "Times"

$metrics
[1] "Times-Roman.afm"      "Times-Bold.afm"       "Times-Italic.afm"     "Times-BoldItalic.afm"
[5] "Symbol.afm"          

$encoding
[1] "default"

attr(,"class")
[1] "Type1Font"